# Hell Knight Signifier Double Dip?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class

I was looking into Hell Knight Signifier builds and [I found a reference to something called the "Divine Double-Dip"](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/322uru/thoughts_on_using_catechesis_to_doubleup_divine/), where (for example) you would take 3 levels of Oracle for a Mystery revelation, and 7 levels of cleric for domain casting. Which would result in, at lvl 20, 13th lvl Oracle casting and 17th level Cleric casting on top of everything the Signifier gives you.

Does "+1 level of spellcasting class" really work like that? That seems like an oddly OP oversight.

Comment: Could you link your source?

Comment: Added source link to original question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It does **not** boost your spellcaster level for both classes.

Re-read the linked reddit post. They're specifically referring to the Catechism ability, which lets your Hellknight Signifier levels stack for purposes of *special abilities*, such as cleric domain powers or oracle mysteries.

An oracle 3 / cleric 7 / Hellknight Signifier 10 would effectively be level 13 for all of their level-dependent oracle mystery effects and level 17 for all of their level-dependent cleric domain powers, but they would have to choose between casting spells as an oracle 13 / cleric 7 or as an oracle 3 / cleric 17 (recommended over the 13/7).

Comment: Or some other middle ground of Caster Level, I think. I can't find the text on it but recall picking CL increase on a per-Prestige-level basis.

Comment: @Ifusaso Yeah, I think you're right. That's probably strictly worse than putting all the CL increases into the same class, though.

Comment: @Ifusaso Some prestige classes indicate that you can choose your progression on a per-level basis, and some don’t. Even among those that do, some limit you to a spellcasting class you had prior to actually becoming that prestige class, while others allow other classes introduced in between the prestige class levels to be selected. And, of course, since the spellcasting boiler plate was almost-certainly copied-and-pasted for each class, it’s extremely unclear when—if ever—those distinctions were even intended. In any event, the point is usually moot because it’s rarely a good idea.

Comment: On which point, I would recommend updating this answer to point out that a 3rd-level oracle/7th-level cleric should be progressing cleric spellcasting. If one wanted oracle spellcasting instead (which is not really a great idea since cleric spellcasting is superior), instead being a 9th-level oracle/1st-level cleric makes vastly more sense. Actually, for that matter, a 1st-level oracle/9th-level cleric is better than the 3/7 version—they only did that for the sake of a second revelation, which might be worth it *at 20th*, but certainly not before then.

Comment: (The point is, you want to maximize your spellcasting from one class, rather than be half-decent at both—being half-decent at both means you aren’t actually *good* at anything.)